# How to avoid \r while looping a multiline string

Tags: bash, sh, aws-cli

I want to loop through the output of an AWS CLI command which gives a multiline string.

I want to split the string into substring, but when I loop through it, `\r` is included in each of the substrings. Why does it happen?

```
#!/bin/bash -ex

physicalId=`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=test-servers" --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId'`
echo physicalId="${physicalId}"

for i in $physicalId; 
do 
echo "$i";
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id $i --output text --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[ImageId]"

done
```

`echo physicalId="${physicalId}"` gives this output:

```
echo 'physicalId=i-0a4a344429075
i-0a2a2aa22a2
i-a0aa212122a2a25'
```

But on looping through the string, it gives `i-0a4a344429075\r` , `i-0a2a2aa22a2\r`, `i-a0aa212122a2a25\r`. Why does this happen? How to remove `\r` from the substring?

Comment: Windows uses `\r\n` as line separator, while Linux uses `\n`, which is why a windows-written line will appear to end with `\r` when read by linux. The `\r`s are probably present in the AWS configuration and should likely be removed from there

Comment: `physicalId=$(aws ec2 ......... | tr -d '\r')`

Comment: Does your Bash script contain DOS carriage returns by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "${physicalId//\\r/}"
```